# Writing to csv in python — delimiters

Tags: python, csv, text

I am trying to write in csv file the result of my code but somehow it writes incorrectly.

My code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

with open('myfile.xml', 'rt') as f:
tree = ET.parse(f)

for sentence in tree.iter('sentence'):
    certainty = sentence.attrib.get('certainty')
    ccue = sentence.find('ccue')
    with open('new_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
       writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|',
                            quotechar='^', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
       if certainty and (ccue is not None):
           writer.writerow('  %s | %s | %s' % (certainty, ''.join(sentence.itertext()), ccue.text))
       else:
           writer.writerow('  %s | | %s' % (certainty,sentence.text))
```

So I want to get such result:
    certainty1|sentence1|ccue1
    certainty2|sentence2|ccue2
    ...
So the delimiter is |.

But my current code writes everything in 1 row and these delimiters are everywhere:

```
| |c|e|r|t|a|i|n|
```

Why does it happen and how can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: `writerow` takes an iterable. read the documentation

Comment: As a separate concern: why are you (re-)opening the CSV file and (re-)creating the writer within the loop? These should be initialized outside the loop.

Comment: @Nick I have tried to move it outside the loop, but than I see the error message `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`. But inside loop it's also wrong, yeah

Comment: @njzk2: strictly speaking, a string *is* an iterable. It just gives (ahem) unexpected results in this case.

Comment: Ah yeah, indentations. Thank you all!

Comment: @ZverArt: I suspect your indentation was wrong, so the `with` was terminated (and the file closed) *before* you got into the loop. The whole `for` loop needs to be *within* the context of the `with`.

Comment: @Nick exactly, so reading the documentation and realizing that a string is iterable should be enough to understand what is happening.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, you're right. I had two problems and you have pointed both of them. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you do that:

```
if certainty and (ccue is not None):
  writer.writerow('  %s | %s | %s' % (certainty, ''.join(sentence.itertext()), ccue.text))
else:
  writer.writerow('  %s | | %s' % (certainty,sentence.text))
```

you're passing a `str` to `writerow`, which expects an *iterable*, so it iterates on your string, and you get 1 cell per char.

Note that you don't have to re-specify the separator, it's already set in the `csv.writer`. You just have to pass your elements as a *list* or *tuple* for instance:

```
if certainty and ccue: # let's simplify your test (ccue is an object or None)
    writer.writerow((certainty,''.join(sentence.itertext()),ccue.text))
else:
    writer.writerow((certainty,'',sentence.text))
```

EDIT: I had left out your other issue, the 1-line problem. For that one, the context handler + csv writer creation below:

```
with open('new_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
   writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|',
                        quotechar='^', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

should be put *outside* the `for` loop else you'll only see the last line in the end (leaving as-is and using append mode is also possible, but less performant)

Comment: Yeah, it writes well now. But the file is being closed after each iteration so the file is not complete :(

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`writer.writerow` takes a `list` and not a string.

Comment: it takes an iterable, actually (tuple, list, generator comprehension...)

Comment: That's exactly the problem: the string *is* an iterable, so iterating over it gives you each character.